# Text field is permanently in label after performing segue

Tags: swift

I have a view controller that has 2 buttons and 2 text fields, and a second view controller that has 1 label. At the moment if I press on buttonOne, the label in the second view controller changes to "text field 1" and when I press buttonTwo, the same label displays "text field 1" again. Ideally I want the label to display "text field" when buttonOne is pressed and "text field 1" when buttonTwo is pressed. Below are the 2 view controllers used and a screen shot of the storyboard and the simulator i'm using. I think the issue is the `secondController.myString = textField.text!` but I can't work out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

**Storyboard**

[image: Storyboard]

**Simulator**

[image: Simulator]

First View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

    var isButtonClicked: Bool = false

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        isButtonClicked = false
    }

    @IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any) {
        if textField.text != "" {
            isButtonClicked = true
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func buttonTwo(_ sender: Any) {

        if textField1.text != ""{
            isButtonClicked = true
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondController.myString = textField.text!
        secondController.myString = textField1.text!
   }
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var myString = String()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = myString
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you made Mistake

```
secondController.myString = textField.text!
secondController.myString = textField1.text!
```

Everytime only `textField1.text` pass to `myString` so it display your textField1 value.

**Do like Below**

```
var isFirstButtonClicked: Bool = false   

@IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any) {
    if textField.text != "" {
        isFirstButtonClicked = true
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonTwo(_ sender: Any) {
    if textField1.text != "" {
        isFirstButtonClicked = false
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

    if isFirstButtonClicked {
        secondController.myString = textField.text!
    }
    else {
        secondController.myString = textField1.text!
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried doing this I end up with the error when I click buttonTwo: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. I have made sure that I am using all of the buttons and labels and they are all referenced in the code but it doesn't seem to work. buttonOne works fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EdwardGallagher, There's no chance for exception by using above code. if your previous code works then this code should work. Make sure your button outlets and actions  successfully binds.

Comment: Ok ill start from scratch to make sure it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just started again and it works!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @EdwardGallagher, That's Great.

Comment: @EdwardGallagher, If This answer helps you then please accept it.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware I had to do that, done it now. I have another question if you're able to answer it? Its regarding multiple labels and multiple text fields. If I ask it as a question I would appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set just text of textField1. What you probably want is set myString in second ViewController depends on which button user pressed.

In storyboard set **tag** of your first button to 1 and of second to 2 
and then in prepare for segue use this

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
if button.tag == 1 {
    secondController.myString = textField.text!
} else {
    secondController.myString = textField1.text!
}
```

also don’t forget to perform segue and pass sender as sender parameter of this perform segue method

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: sender)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up using Kuldeeps code but I appreciate your time that you invested!